# Way to filter by row group count > 1

Tags: custom-reports

Requirement is to filter for report with multiple complaints for same customer. Added account as grouping by row but unable to filter the group count > 1 kinda of statement. How to achieve this in salesforce reports.
I am looking for a simple Group by field having count > 1 sql statement...
Unbelievable I have to post such a question as documentation is not available about this functionality. please help.

Comment: great idea & workaround for SF dev unability to provide this obvious enhancment [filter on record_count; unfortunately, as an end user, the odds of our organization SF admin ever approving/authorizing this workaround is near zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a report.

Refer the [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYVsUAN/limit-rows-by-grouping-not-total-report)

But you can certainly do this with a query.

Go to the Developer Console, click on the Query Editor tab, and enter the query as follows:

```
select count(id) CaeCount, accountid Id
from Case 
group by accountid
having count(id) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a custom field `Case_Count__c` on Account
- Use [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to roll up the Count of Cases to this field

  - Use Calculation Mode = `Scheduled` to run a one-time job to update all Accounts; then switch to Calculation Mode `Realtime`
- Change your report filter to include on Accounts where `Case_Count__c` > 1