# Sort by sum or eliminate less than 2 records on a report

Tags: report-formula

I would like to sort by sum on a report. A sum count formula was created on the report. See screenshot attached.

I want to only have Inquiry count of 2 or more records and remove anything less than 2. Right now it shows records with 1.

Is there a way to sort by sum for the sum count formula field?

[image]

I have tried clicking the Inquiry to see if it can sort but it doesn't show anything.

In regards to filter, I tried filtering by Inquiry Count Formula sum field but it says no data found.

See screenshot attached.

[image]

[image]

Can someone assist with this? I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am like to inform this is similar to question [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381013/way-to-filter-by-row-group-count-1#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20custom%20field%20Case_Count__c%20on%20Account%20Use,to%20include%20on%20Accounts%20where%20Case_Count__c%20%3E%201). currently we don't have this functionality in Salesforce. The mentioned functionality is still available as [Idea 1](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdf5NUAR/limit-row-count-in-summary-and-matrix-reports) and [Idea 2](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjTGUAZ/filter-record-count-in-reports-criteria) in Salesforce.

Hope it's GA in future if the team will give the priority.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: Hi Mohanraj, Is there a workaround to achieve this in the backend such as running a query in dev console?

Comment: @Chantel Sorry, currently we don't have the work around directly. but you can use the SOQL Query as like follows, `SELECT count(id), <OrderId> FROM <Inquiry object api name> WHERE <OrderId> != Null Group BY '<OrderId>' Limit 200`. This report result provided the count of Inquiry records per order. So after you can able to export the the results and filter out the records which are not more then 2 records.

Comment: Hi Mohanraj, will I be exporting this from Dev console, or from Reports section. Because I exported the report to csv from reports section without running the query provided, and it looks I am not able to filter for some reason. Also, what happens when I run this query?

Comment: Also, do you know if a formula can be done within the report to only show more than 1 record for inquiries?